# Unordered lists border does not wrap the lists items

Tags: css

Maybe you can help....
I have this unordered list and it does not look right and my css power is limited:)

**The border of the ul element does not wrap the entire list.**

Please take a look at it's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sexywebteacher/CWh2Z/1/):

Ty!

Comment: You need to tell us what your goal is. *It does not look right* does not help.

Comment: We're supposed to guess what "looking right" is?

Comment: Why do you want to set the list items with the CSS rule float:left; Removing that line will fix the border around the unordered list.

Comment: Sorry about that, update the question - it's the border

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
ul {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

or just `overflow:auto;` to your existing #lo style.

Answer (score 1):

from the style **#lo li**

remove **`float: left;`**

and add:

**`display: inline-block;`**